# What is the most robust way to update some sub-class property in tandem with another?

Tags: python

Title might be a little vague, though I'd rather it be a little too vague rather than a little too specific, in case I'm approaching this wrong.

I have two classes: `Vector`, which represents a 2d coordinate position, and `Entity`, which contains two of these vectors, named `position` and `tile_position`. Both classes use  `property` getters and setters for their attributes:

```py
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y)
        self.data = [x, y]
    
    @property
    def x(self)
        return self.data[0]

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value)
        self.data[0] = value

    # Similar for y

class Entity:
    def __init__(self)
        self._position = Vector(...)
        self._tile_position = Vector(...)

        self.tile_width = int(...)
        self.tile_height = int(...)

    @property
    def position(self):
        return self._position
    
    # etc, etc.
```

I would like to make it so that `position` and `entity_position` are updated in tandem, so when one is updated the other updates immediately afterward. Their relationship can be described by the following functions:

```py
def tile_to_position(entity, x, y):
    return (x + entity.tile_width / 2, y + entity.tile_height / 2)

def position_to_tile(entity, x, y):
    return (round(x - entity.tile_width / 2), round(y - entity.tile_height / 2))
```

Note the argument `entity` to get the `tile_width` and `tile_height`. This is necessary because these parameters are different for every entity instance and can also change during runtime.

Currently, I have `Entity.position.setter` and `Entity.tile_position.setter` set up like this:

```py
@position.setter
def position(self, value):
    # Get the x and y components from value
    x, y = extract_from(value)
    # Update our position in place
    self._position.x = x
    self._position.y = y
    # Then calculate where our conjugate should be and update that
    tx, ty = position_to_tile(self, x, y)
    self._tile_position.x = tx
    self._tile_position.y = ty
```

This works perfectly when setting `Entity.position` or `Entity.tile_position`:

```py
entity = Entity(tile_width = 1, tile_height = 1)

entity.position = [10.5, 10.5]
print(entity.tile_position) # Vector(10, 10)
# Converse works as well
entity.tile_position = [1, 1]
print(entity.position) # Vector(1.5, 1.5)
```

But predictably fails when setting `Entity.(tile_)position.x` or `Entity.(tile_)position.y`:

```py
# Set to a known position
entity.position = [0.5, 0.5]
# Ideally the following statement would update `tile_position` as well
entity.position.x = 10
# But it doesn't, because `Entity.position.setter` was not called, `Vector.x.setter` was
print(entity.tile_position) # Vector(0, 0)
```

What would be the most elegant way to have editing the x or y attribute also update the other vector? I've tried keeping a copy of `entity` in `Vector` and do the transformation in `Vector.x.setter`, but this seems like an anti-pattern; a Vector should have no knowledge of it's parent, especially since `Vector` is intended to be a general-use construct, not tied to `Entity` specifically. Furthermore, adding such a member would create a circular reference, which would prevent `del entity` from immediately freeing the entity's resources, which I would like to avoid out of preference.

I think the "best" solution would be to provide another set of custom methods in `Entity` that would override the x/y ones provided by `Vector` when accessing from `Entity`; something along the lines of:

```py
class Entity:
    # ...
    @position.x.setter
    def position_x(self, x):
        self._position.data[0] = x
        self._tile_position.data[0] = round(x - self.tile_width / 2)

    @position.y.setter
    def position_y(self, y):
        self._position.data[1] = y
        self._tile_position.data[1] = round(y - self.tile_height / 2)

    # Similar for `tile_position`
```

Is this possible? If not, how should I instead go about doing this?

**EDIT**

Per comment suggestions, I can change `tile_position` to be based off of `position` so there's only one set of data:

```py
@tile_position.setter
def tile_position(self, value):
    return Vector(*position_to_tile(self._position))
```

However, setting `Entity.tile_position.x/y` doesn't affect `Entity.position`:

```py
entity.position.x = 10 # Affects `tile_position` as desired
entity.tile_position.y = 10 # Does not affect `position` at all
```

Comment: Are you sure you want two different attributes, rather than two properties that are computed from a single source of truth?

Comment: As already noted, don't save both if one can always be calculated from the other.

Comment: It would simplify it, but not quite solve it from what I can tell. Suppose I make `position` the truth value and construct a new Vector for `tile_position` based on `position`. Updating `position.x` now correctly updates `tile_position.x`, but changing `tile_position.x` now cannot update `position.x`; ideally it should be bidirectional. Or am I misunderstanding the suggestion?

Comment: `entity_position` -> `_tile_position`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have figured out the main answer: any time you have redundant information, don't do it. The only exception is if it's expensive to compute, in which case there are workarounds, like caching.

The reason that something like `entity.tile_position.y` does not work is because you've presumably added a getter that generated a new `Vector` for the tile position every time you request `entity.tile_position`. So calling the setter for `y` on a temporary object clearly does not affect anything.

I can think of a couple of workarounds, ordered in decreasing preference:

1. Simplify your code. There is no real need for a `Vector` class from what you show here. It adds a bunch of wrappers to two integers. Instead define entity to have attributes `x` and `y` (no need to redirect to a list), and properties for `tile_x`, `tile_y`:

   ```
   class Entity:
       def __init__(self):
           self._x = ...
           self._y = ...
           self.tile_width = ...
           self.tile_height = ...

       @property
       def x(self):
           return self._x

       @x.setter
       def x(self, value):
           self._x = value

       @property
       def tile_x(self):
           return round(self._x - self.tile_width / 2)

       @tile_x.setter
       def tile_x(self, value):
            self._x = value + self.tile_width / 2

       ...
   ```

   You could of course make functions that accept a tile coordinate and dimension to avoid replicating the conversion code for x and y.
2. Create a version of the `Vector` class that does writeback:

   ```
   class TileVector(Vector):
       def __init__(self, x, y, parent):
           super().__init__(x, y)
           self.parent = parent

       @Vector.x.setter
       def x(self, value):
           self._x = value
           self.parent.x = tile_to_xy(self.parent, value, 0)[0]
   ```

   Return this type for the `tile_position` getter in `Entity`, so you have a reference to the parent.

Comment: While I'm rather disturbed I didn't think of having one true value and calulating the other on the fly, for technical and data-structure reasons I would still like the user to be able to both use `position = ...` and `position.x = ...`. After thinking about it a little more, going with writeback seems the most sensible, and I can even get rid of my circular reference gripe by wrapping `TileVector.parent` in a `weakref`. Still clunky though, so if anyone _can_ get away with option 1, they should.

Comment: @RedRuin. A weak reference would not be appropriate if you want to guarantee write-back